# Linked List: displayList function prints the last element

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm stuck at printing the strings of my linked list. I don't know why but my program is printing the last element inserted. I've checked it multiple times, and i can't seem to find the mistake. I would really appreciate If anyone could tell me where did it go wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    char* data;
    struct node *nextPtr; //Address of the next node
}; 

struct node *startNode;

//Function to create the list
static void createNodeList(int totalNodes);

//Function to display the list
static void displayList();

int main(void)
{
   int numberOfNodes;
   printf("Input the number of nodes: ");
   scanf("%d", &numberOfNodes);
   createNodeList(numberOfNodes);
   
   displayList();
    return 0;
}


static void createNodeList(int totalNodes){
    struct node *newNode;
    struct node *nodeBuffer;
    char *nodeData;
    int nodeCounter;
    //Allocate memory for starting node
    startNode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    if(startNode==NULL){
        printf("Memory can not be allocated");
    }
    else{
        printf("Input data for node 1: ");
        scanf("%s", nodeData);
        startNode->data = nodeData;
        startNode->nextPtr = NULL;
        
        nodeBuffer=startNode;
        
        for(nodeCounter=2; nodeCounter <=totalNodes; nodeCounter++){
            newNode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            
            if(newNode==NULL){
                printf("Memmory cannot be alocated");
                
            }
            else{
                printf("Input data for node %d: ", nodeCounter);
                scanf("%s", nodeData);
                newNode->data=nodeData;
                newNode->nextPtr=NULL;
                //Links the previous node to the current node
               nodeBuffer->nextPtr=newNode;
                //Copies the address of the current node
               nodeBuffer = nodeBuffer->nextPtr;
            }
        
        
    }
        
    }
}

static void displayList(){
    struct node *nodeBuffer;
    nodeBuffer = startNode;
    
    if(nodeBuffer==NULL){
        printf("list empty");
    }
    
    else{
        while(nodeBuffer !=NULL){
            printf("Data=%s \n", nodeBuffer->data);
            //Go to the next node
            nodeBuffer=nodeBuffer->nextPtr;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler response:

```
Input the number of nodes: 5
Input data for node 1: a
Input data for node 2: b
Input data for node 3: c
Input data for node 4: d
Input data for node 5: e
Data=e 
Data=e 
Data=e 
Data=e 
Data=e
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `char *nodeData`  I see a pointer, but nothing for it to point to.

Comment: You have the pointer `nodeData`, but ***where does it point?***

Comment: As for the problem you experience, think about what the assignment `startNode->data = nodeData` does. Hint: It does *not* copy whatever `nodeData` points to.

Comment: Think about whether it makes sense to hardcode global variables into functions.

Comment: @vlad Take into account that it is not a good idea to declare functions that provide the interface as static.